# Deleting certain characters that occur between certain other characters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to delete all rows of e-mails in a Google Spreadsheet in which there are two or less characters between (i) a hyphen (-) or full-stop (.) and (ii) the @ sign. The e-mails are typically in the format of firstname.surname@email.com, so e-mails with surnames that are two or less characters need to be removed.  This is what I have so far:

```
function removeRowsWithTwoOrLessChars() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();
 var rowsDeleted = 0;

 var colIndex = 0; 
 for(var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {


    var charBefore = String(values[i][colIndex]).indexOf("@");
  if(charBefore < 3) {
   sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
   rowsDeleted++; 
  } 

 var charAfter = String(values[i][colIndex]).indexOf(".");
  if(charAfter < 3) {
   sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
   rowsDeleted++; 
  } 
 }
};
```

The trouble is that this does not distinguish between the first full-stop that occurs between the first- and surname, and the second (or more) full-stops that occur elsewhere in the email.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The purpose of the function is to remove rows in which the surname of the user is two or less characters whenever the surname occurs after the first full-stop (or underscore or hyphen).  The problem is that the function just doesn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The trouble is that this does not distinguish between the first
>   full-stop that occurs between the first- and surname, and the second
>   (or more) full-stops that occur elsewhere in the email.

One solution would be to replace your multiple tests using `indexOf()` with [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), like so:

```
var bad_address = values[i][colIndex].match(/[\.\-][^@]{1,2}@/)

if( bad_address ){
    # ...
}
```

`match()` tries to find patterns in a string using a [regular expression](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

The regex used above breaks down as follows:

```
/         -- start the regular expression
[\.\-]    -- match a single . or -
[^@]{1,2} -- match any character except for @, once or twice
@         -- match a single @ character
/         -- end the regular expression
```

Since the pattern only matches `.` or `-` that are one or two characters before the `@` in the email, you won't have to worry about matching them at other places in the email address.

Also, `i` will already by an integer, so you shouldn't need `parseInt()`.

Putting it all together, you'd get:

```
function removeRowsWithTwoOrLessChars() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();
    var rowsDeleted = 0;

    var colIndex = 0; 
    for(var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
        var bad_address = values[i][colIndex].match(/[\.\-][^@]{1,2}@/);

        if( bad_address ){
            sheet.deleteRow(i + 1 - rowsDeleted);
            rowsDeleted++; 
        } 
    }
};
```

Hope this helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Zak.  It looks quite helpful but I'm afraid I don't follow.  Could you please show me the modified form of my code?

Comment: No worries, @EdDev - I've added the complete code to the answer.

Comment: Good point. While you don't have to escape `.` inside of character classes (or `-` when you don't have a character range like `[a-z]`), it's better to do so and avoid problems when you quickly add a character to the class without thinking and find that you now match a bunch of characters you didn't expect. eg. `[.-:]`

Comment: I wonder whether I might trouble you with a follow-up question.  What change would i need to make to `var bad_address = values[i][colIndex].match(/[\.\-][^@]{1,2}@/)` in order to delete rows with emails in which the firstname is one character or less?

Comment: Just change the regular expression between the two slashes (`/`) with `^.[\.\-]`. The `^` forces the regex to match at the start of the string. The `.` matches any character (except newlines). `[\.\-]` matches either `.` or `-`. Putting it all together, you'd get `var bad_address = values[i][colIndex].match(/^.[\.\-]/)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, as the sheet still retains entries such as f.surname@email.com and f_surname@email.com

Comment: The regex will match `f.surname@email.com`, but it won't match `f_surname@email.com` (as the character class to match the second character doesn't contain `_`). The class would need to be `[\.\-_]` instead of `[\.\-]`.

Comment: Thank you, Zak.  I tried that, too, but it is removing neither the rows with f. nor f_

Comment: Hi Ed - I'm quite sure that the regular expression works. Looking at the rest of the code, I would guess that the index in your `for` loop is off by one. Try setting `i` to `0` and see what happens.